# setup_module and setup_func in nose

Tags: python, unit-testing, nose

I am trying out writting tests in nose, but I need some help with logic of setups for module and func.

```
def setup_func():
    q_object = u'item'
    retry_in = 20

@with_setup(setup_func)
def test_set():
    assert q_object == u'item'
```

When I run nosetests I get following error :

```
NameError: global name 'q_object' is not defined
```

So how do I access q_object in my test function? 
And how I access object from setup_module() in specific test class?

I figured out setup_module.

```
setup_module(module):
    module.item = u'item'
```

Than in module I simple use that created object - item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you're trying to access global variable in you tests. So, your code should look somewhat like this.

```
q_object = None

def setup_func():
    global q_object
    q_object = u'item'

@with_setup(setup_func)
def test_set():
    global q_object
    assert q_object == u'item'
```

But using global variables — really isn't a good idea. Try to find another way that will allow you avoid them.

I think tests classes will suit you perfectly

```
class ExampleTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.q_object = u'item'

    def test_a(self):
        assert self.q_object == u'item'
```

It's still not perfect (same global vars solution), but at least wrapped inside the class.

Comment: I follow example from there. https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/writing_tests.html

There is no possibility to write setup_func without globals?

For example the setup_module function I provided in example, nose let me use object 'item' in any part of modul, function, class, method.

Comment: I've updated my post to show example of wrapping tests into classes. It's better then globals because at least it isolates vars from global context.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I understand logic of wrapping tests into cases. I write a paper about testing in nose and I wanted to give example of using setup_func function.
I was just curious if I can bypass usage of global here. For example when I use setup_module to setup object item, I can access it without refering as global in any part of tests in module. Nose knows what object I am refering to.
This is Nose related specific question.

Comment: I'm not sure, but addinv variable to module — is the same as adding it into globals. Anyway — setup_func isn't for setting variable. That's why I'm suggesting ways to avoid it.

Answer (score 2):

This code worked for me in nose:

It incorporates the best of both worlds. Classes to hold the scope and a slightly cleaner test than the default unittest2 framework.

```
class TestSomething(object):

  def setup(self):
    self.q_object = u'item'

  def test_set(self):
    eq_(self.q_object, u'item')
```